# manipulate regexp-search matches using `query-regexp-replace` in a defun

Tags: regex, search, replace, emacs

Since version 22 of Emacs, we can use `\,(function)` for manipualting (parts of) the regex-search result before replacing it. But – this is mentioned often, but nonetheless still the truth – we can use this construct only in the standard interactive way. (Interactive like: By pressing `C-M-%` or calling `query-replace-regexp` with `M-x`.)

As an example:

If we have

- [Foo Bar 1900]

and want to get

- [Foo Bar \function{foo1900}{1900}]

we can use:

```
M-x query-replace-regexp <return>
  \[\([A-Za-z-]+\)\([^0-9]*\) \([0-9]\{4\}\)\]    
  [\1\2 \\function{\,(downcase \1)\3}{\3}]
```

to get it done. So this can be done pretty easy.

In my own defun, *I* can use query only by replacing without freely modifying the match, **or** modify the prepared replaced string without any querying. The only way I see, is to serialize it in such a way:

```
(defun form-to-function () 
  (interactive)
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (while (query-replace-regexp 
    "\\[\\([A-Za-z-]+\\)\\([^0-9]*\\) \\([0-9]\\{4\\}\\)\\]" 
    "[\\1\\2 \\\\function{\\1\\3}{\\3}]" ))
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (while (search-forward-regexp "\\([a-z0-9]\\)" nil t) 
    (replace-match (downcase (match-string 1)) t nil)
 )
)
```

For me the **query** is important, because I can't be sure, what the buffer offers me (= I can't be sure, the author used this kind of string always in the same manner).

I want to use an elisp function, because it is not the only recurring replacement (and also not only one buffer (I know about `dired-do-query-replace-regexp` but I prefer working buffer-by-buffer with replace-defuns)).

At first I thought I only miss something like a `query-replace-match` to use instead of `replace-match`. But I fear, I am also missing the easy and flexible way of rearrange the string the the `query-replace-regexp`.

So I think, I need a `\,` for use in an defun. And I really wonder, if I am the only one, who is missing this feature.

Comment: As you say `query-replace-regexp` is for interactive use only. In lisp code one uses `read-key` or `y-or-n-p` to query the user whether to replace the text or not. AFAIK, the only reasonable way to modify the behaviour of `query-replace-regexp` temporarily is to let `replace-re-search-function` to a function which replaces the action of `re-search-forward` in `query-replace-regexp`.  Note, you should replace `(goto-char 1)` with `(goto-char (point-min))` in your code. That leaves the user more freedom to restrict the area to be processed.

Comment: @Tobias: As Stefan mentioned, I can use `query-replace-regexp` in a defun, also it is not suggested. (Perhaps because a query is not thought as a wish?) But anyway, I fear I wasn't precise enough. I don't want to modify the behaviour of `query-replace-regexp`, I want to use the functionality I have with [C-M-%] combined with `\,` in a defun. In other words: I'm searching for an easy to use search and manipulate replace function for my defun. Thank you very much, also for pointing me to use `(point-min)` instead of just `1`. I refined my question.

Comment: I think `read-key` and `y-or-no-p` just asks for approval but doesn't present the highlighted match and moreover doesn't show the resulting replacement in the minibuffer, which is very convenient.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your rsearch&replace to prompt the user, that means you want it to be interactive, so it's perfectly OK to call `query-replace-regexp` (even if the byte-compiler will tell you that this is meant for interactive use only).  If the warning bothers you, you can either wrap the call in `with-no-warnings` or call `perform-replace` instead.

The docstring of `perform-replace` sadly doesn't (or rather "didn't" until today) say what is the format of the `replacements` argument, but you can see it in the function's code:

```
;; REPLACEMENTS is either a string, a list of strings, or a cons cell
;; containing a function and its first argument.  The function is
;; called to generate each replacement like this:
;;   (funcall (car replacements) (cdr replacements) replace-count)
;; It must return a string.
```

Comment: I did not get the point, why it seems to be unsuggested using the `query-replace-regexp` in a defun, but I've never seen a warning, because I've never thought to byte-compile the .el file, I think because of the heavy use of query it'll me, who slows down the process.

Comment: And: I have to admit, I don't get to use `perform-replace`. Does it replace the `query-replace-regexp` or just the `replace-match` in a loop with `re-search-forward`? What I didn't know until now, the replacement of an `query-replace-regexp` doesn't have to be a string, one can also use a list.

Comment: `C-h f perform-replace` should explain that: it does search and replace in a loop.

Comment: At the first try, I did not understand the help of `perform-replace`, but anyway, my problem was the forming of the replacement element of the defun. As it is the same as for `query-replace-regexp`, your answer didn't achieve what I thought I was asking for. But it helped me a lot indeed, that's why I'll upvote it anywaym, as soon as I am allowed to.

Comment: BTW, the reason why we discourage the use of `query-replace-regexp` in Elisp is because it is too common for beginners to use this function (presumably because it's the one they know from interactive use) when they really don't want all the interactive part of it (they just want to unconditionally search&replace all the matches), in which case they should use the simple while loop shown in the docstring instead.  Clearly, you're in a different situation, because you *do* want to use the interactive features.

Answer (score 1):

The `query-replace-function` can handle replacement not only as a string, but as a list including the manipulating elements. The use of `concat` archives building an string from various elements.

So one who wants to manipulate the search match by a function before inserting the replacement can use `query-replace-regexp` also in a defun.

```
(defun form-to-function () 
  (interactive)
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (query-replace-regexp 
   "\\[\\([A-Za-z-]+\\)\\([^0-9]*\\) \\([0-9]\\{4\\}\\)\\]"
   (quote (replace-eval-replacement concat "[\\1\\2 \\\\function{" 
    (replace-quote (downcase (match-string 1))) "\\3}{\\3}]")) nil ))
```

- `match-string 1` returns the first expression of our regexp-search.
- `replace-quote' helps us doublequoting the following expression.
- `concat` forms a string from the following elements.

and

- `replace-eval-replacement` is not documented.

Why it is in use here nevertheless, is because of emacs seems to use it internally, while performing the first »interactive« `query-replace-regexp` call. At least is it given by asking emacs with `repeat-complex-command`.

I came across `repeat-complex-command` (bound to [C-x M-:].) while searching for an answer in the source code of `query-replace-regexp`.

So an easy to create defun could be archieved by performing the standard search and replace way as told in the question and after first sucess pressing [C-x M-:] results in an already Lisp formed command, which can be copied and pasted in a defun.

### Edit (`perform-replace`)

As Stefan mentioned, one can use `perform-replace` to avoid using `query-replace-regexp`.

Such a function could be:

```
(defun form-to-function () 
  (interactive)
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (while (perform-replace
      "\\[\\([A-Za-z-]+\\)\\([^0-9]*\\) \\([0-9]\\{4\\}\\)\\]"
      (quote (replace-eval-replacement concat "[\\1\\2 \\\\function{"
      (replace-quote (downcase (match-string 1))) "\\3}{\\3}]"))
       t t nil)))
```

The first boolean (t) is a query flag, the second is the regexp switch. So it works also perfectly, but it didn't help finding the replacement expression as easy as in using `\,`.